# Open sets on a Stone space

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, lattice-theory, boolean-algebras

If $B$ is a Boolean algebra (possibly assumed complete), is there a standard name for the Heyting algebra (or frame) $L := \Omega(S(B))$ of open sets on the Stone space $S(B)$ of $B$, — or for the functor taking $B$ to $L$?  Where might I find a summary of the properties of this functor (if possible, purely at the algebraic level, without reference to the Stone space itself), beyond the fact that $B$ can be recovered as the set of complemented elements of $L$?

(I searched, of course, in Johnstone's book *Stone Spaces*, but could not find anything.  I might very well have missed a reference there, though, because everything seems tantalizingly close.)

**Edit:** I didn't realize it, but $L$ is just the lattice of ideals of $B$: see Monk, & Bonnet eds. (Koppelberg), *Handbook of Boolean Algebras* (1989), chap 3, thm 7.25.  See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3016998/characterization-of-zero-dimensional-frames-via-lattices-of-ideals) for a characterization of the the (essential) image of the functor.  This makes my question a bit silly, and I will vote to close it (but not delete it outright, since this paragraph can still be of some interest).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has a simple answer (see last edit/paragraph).

Comment: Closing makes no sense, since it's just a slow deletion. Either delete it or self-answer it and accept your own answer? (better the 2nd solution)

Comment: @YCor Ah, I thought closing just made it impossible to answer (the StackExchange rules really are a bit arcane). Slow deletion might still make sense to allow upvoters to read the answer without the question remaining perpetually on archive. But you're right, I'll try to find the time to write a slightly better account of the properties of the "lattice of ideals" functor as an answer. Or if the question is closed in the mean time, so be it.